# How can i Point to the Oracle JDK in my Ubuntu.

Tags: command-line

When I run: `java -version`. It returns OpenJdk. But I have intalled Oracle JDK. How can I point to the Oracle JDK.

Please Some one answer me?

Comment: Since you are a new user, if the following post helped you please mark the post as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following lines in your `~/.bashrc` file.

> `export JAVA_HOME=<path/to/java>`

`<path/to/java>` will be something like `/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java` depending on which version you've installed.

You can also set the default java to use by running the below command and selecting the desired options from the list:

> `sudo update-alternatives --config java`